# How can you programmatically check for the appearance proxy?

Tags: ios

I added the following code to make use of appearance on newer versions of the OS while not doing anything for older versions:

```
if ([UINavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])
{
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

It compiled ok, and seems to be working.

Then I turned on a bunch of build warnings that are disabled by default in Xcode and started getting the error "Unimplemented selector 'appearance'".

So what is the correct way to check at run time if appearance is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
if ([UIBarButtonItem conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIAppearance)])
{
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. The UIView header claims to conform to the UIAppearance protocol, so you'll have to know what you're doing beforehand. Checking for the appearance selector is unreliable. Additionally, you have to know which properties support UIAppearance, as not all of the obvious properties do.

However, if you're looking to know which classes and properties support UIAppearance, there's hope. I've grepped the UIKit headers for iOS 5, and I'm sure you can do the same for iOS 6 if you're curious about potential changes. My list of UIView subclasses that conform to UIAppearance lives [on my blog, here](http://blog.mosheberman.com/list-of-classes-that-support-uiappearance-in-ios-5/).

**Edit:**

I forgot about the `conformsToProtocol:` method that CSmith mentions in his answer. Regardless, I'm leaving this answer up because the link is still relevant.